# Is it grammatically correct to say omae ga yorobe?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

おまえ が喜べ 
You're happy/you rejoice

Comment: 喜べ's reading is yorokobe, not yorobe, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, おまえが喜べ is grammatically correct, but おまえ is a rude way to address a person and 喜べ is in the imperative form. Overall, the sentence is far from polite, and sounds like you're demanding an action. Unless you actually want to mean that on purpose, it's safer to say either

> 幸せそうですね

or

> 楽しそうですね